# Why can a method definition without a block parameter accept a block?

Tags: ruby

Why can a method definition without a block parameter accept a block? This is the demo code:

```
def fun
 yield
end
fun {puts 'hello ruby'}
```

Comment: Have you been on Codecademy :)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because that's how ruby works. Any method can be passed a block. It is responsibility of that method to check if [`block_given?`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/block_given%3F) and `yield` to it if needed.

This is implicit block passing. When you declare a block parameter, then something different happens: the block is converted to a Proc object, so that it can be called like a function and passed around as a parameter. You can't do that with implicit blocks (AFAIK).

```
def foo &block
  block.call 3
  bar block
end

# this method expects proc as a regular parameter (not a block), so you can pass  
#   a block in addition to it (if you so desire)
def bar block
  block.call 4
end

foo do |x|
  puts "this is #{x}"
end
# >> this is 3
# >> this is 4
```

Comment: "Because that's how ruby works." Yep, that's *exactly* the phrase I would have used. There is no need for any other answer (or, indeed, for the rest of this answer).

Comment: @matt: without the rest, the answer would be too short for an answer :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev what is the difference between `def foo &block` and `def bar block`?

Comment: @iAmRubuuu: in `bar` the parameter `block` is not a block. It's a proc. Try this link: [Understanding Blocks, Procs and Lambdas](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev looks like the link has moved: http://www.reactive.io/tips/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/

Comment: @drewish: Ah, you mean the link from comments? Thanks for posting the new one.